# Testing code which calls native methods

Tags: java, junit, easymock, mockito, powermock

I have a class like this:

```
public final class Foo
{
    public native int getBar();

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Bar: " + getBar();
    }
}
```

Please note that *getBar()* is implemented with JNI and that the class is *final*. I want to write a junit test to test the *toString()* method. For this I need to mock the *getBar()* method and then run the original *toString()* method to check the output.

My first thought was that this must be impossible but then I found [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) which supports testing final classes and native methods according to the feature list. But so far I had no success with it. The best thing I managed was mocking the complete class but then the test tested the mocked *toString()* method instead of the real one which doesn't make much sense.

So how can I use PowerMock to test this *toString()* method from above? I prefer using PowerMock with [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) but if this is not possible I have no problem with using [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it. The way I was doing it was correct. The only thing I missed was telling the mock object to call the original method when toString was called(). So it works like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Foo.class })
public class FooTest
{
    @Test
    public void testToString() throws Exception
    {
        Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);
        when(foo.getBar()).thenReturn(42);
        when(foo.toString()).thenCallRealMethod();
        assertEquals("Bar: 42", foo.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: HI... I cant add the "when()".. why..? Can you please tell me using Easymock

Answer (score 3):

Or use [JMockit](http://jmockit.org/) with *dynamic partial mocking*:

```
import org.junit.*;
import mockit.*;

public class FooTest
{
    @Test
    public void testToString()
    {
        final Foo foo = new Foo();
        new Expectations(foo) {{ foo.getBar(); result = 42; }};

        assertEquals("Bar: 42", foo.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use **Strategy Pattern**:

```
    public final class Foo
    {
        public IBarStrategy barStrategy;

        ......
    }

    interface IBarStrategy{
        int getBar();
    }
```

When unit test, inject a mock `IBarStrategy` instance, then you could test class `Foo`.

Comment: Dependency injection is a nice thing for code re-use and modularity but if that's not needed then why should I increase the complexity and loosen the API of my classes just for testability? But that's not the point here. So let's say I can't change the test subject so I can't extract the native methods into an interface.

Comment: you're not actually increasing the complexity by doing this.  your just hiding complexity by NOT doing this.  you should be designing for testability to begin with