# Can't Mockito mock a class with a native init method

Tags: java, mockito

**native init method** I mean it is
a field in a class init by a native method. This is my code.

```
class Operator {
    private sr = new SR();
    ...
}

class SR {
    public SR() {
        aNative.new_instance(); // where the native method is called
    }
}
```

when I mock the Operator, it will throw an exception:
**Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type**

My java version is 8. the mockito-inline version is 3.9.0. the bytebuddy version is 1.10.20. I used to change the java version to 11 but it does not work.

I can mock other classes without a native init method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mockito does not support mocking native methods:
[Mockito - mocking classes with native methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223698/mockito-mocking-classes-with-native-methods#answer-10223788)

One option would be Powermock.